# Cannot Create Android Project using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio downloaded from the Android website.
I downloaded android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

When I go to Open->New Project I do not see the option to create a New Android project.

Thanks

[image: New Project Options in Android Studio]

Comment: Check SDK path and give some more details

Comment: @PuneetSahota Dude you need to download sdk and java jdk so as to run android studio....

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the Android Studio, but you didn't installed the Android SDK & other tools. First install the Android SDK & enter its path in SDK Location, then you will be able to make a new project. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Java JDK. After installation of JDK set environment variable.
you can get JDK here. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Here you know how to set an environment variable. https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

If you don't know how to download SDK and set path. Then you simply download the complete package (Android studio with SDK). It will give you both Studio and SDK so it won't ask you like this dialog.

You can get complete bundle here https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.3.0/android-studio-bundle-162.4069837-windows.exe